# How to make Bitmap image from StackPanel in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'd like to make a application, like [this one](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/05fec2f6-86a1-4113-be46-c5c7cf973cf9). The application enables to make a tile with text.

I found that I couldn't write text in tile easily, because StandardTileData class dosen't have such a function to write text in tile. StandardTileData class just enables to set Title, BackgroundImage, Count, etc. The sample is like this.

```
StandardTileData secondaryTile = new StandardTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("/TileColors..png", UriKind.Relative),
    Title = "title",
    Count = null,
};
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?id=1", UriKind.Relative), secondaryTile);
```

So, I think we may need to make bitmap image included text. I don't have other good ideas.
Does anyone know how to make bitmap image from stackpanel ?

My code is like this,

```
<StackPanel Height="173" Width="173" x:Name="TilePanel" Background="Wheat" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="tileText" Text="I'd like to add the text to a tile." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontSize="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe that function will help you out:

```
    public static void SaveToIsolatedStorage(FrameworkElement element, string file, bool scaled=true)
    {
        try
        {
            var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
            IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            double width = Math.Round(element.ActualWidth * ((double)Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100f), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            double height = Math.Round(element.ActualHeight * ((double)Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100f), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

            if (!scaled)
            {
                width = element.ActualWidth;
                height = element.ActualHeight;
            }


            using (var stream = iso.CreateFile(file))
            {
                bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, (int)width, (int)height, 0, 100);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        } 
    }
```

Usage:

```
    SaveToIsolatedStorage(uiElement, "uiElement_as_screenshot.jpg");
```

Edith: it seems i am late on this one but it could help anyone else ;)